# How do I align cases of a defined function?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Here I have this piece of code.

```
 \[
    (e^{2\pi i t},s)\mapsto \begin{cases} 
    \alpha(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}t(s+1)})   & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \\ 
    \beta(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s+t+1)})    & \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \\ 
    \gamma(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s(1-t)+\frac{1}{2}(t+1))})   & \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1 \\
    \end{cases}
 \]
```

And I would like to align the cases so that `t` is centered on all cases. Which command do I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the widest element on the left as a `\phantom`, and `\mathllap` the rest (needs [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  (e^{2\pi i t},s) \mapsto \begin{cases} 
    \alpha(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}t(s+1)})                    & 
      \phantom{\frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4}}\mathllap{0} \leq t < \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \\ 
    \beta(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s+t+1)})                    & 
      \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \leq t < \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \\ 
    \gamma(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s(1-t)+\frac{1}{2}(t+1))}) & 
      \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \\
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `aligned` can give precise alignment without using `phantom`s. Note also the size of parens is more proportionate using `\big` and two-character fractions, like 1/2, can be shortly written as '\frac12'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
(e^{2\pi i t},s)\mapsto\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
  &\alpha\big(e^{2\pi i\frac14t(s+1)}\big)                &            0                & \le t \le \tfrac12s+(1-s)\tfrac14 \\
  &\beta\big(e^{2\pi i\frac14(s+t+1)}\big)                & \tfrac12s+(1-s)\tfrac{1}{4} & \le t \le \tfrac34s+(1-s)\tfrac12 \\
  &\gamma\big(e^{2\pi i\frac14(s(1-t)+\frac12(t+1))}\big) & \tfrac34s+(1-s)\tfrac12     & \le t \le 1 
\end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No `\phantom` is necessary with this align-TABstack approach.  Plus, inter-row baselineskip is easily settable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\[
  (e^{2\pi i t},s) \mapsto \left\{
  \alignCenterstack{
    &\alpha(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}t(s+1)})                    & 
      0 \leq& t < \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \\ 
    &\beta(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s+t+1)})                    & 
      \frac{1}{2}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{4} \leq& t < \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \\ 
    &\gamma(e^{2\pi i \frac{1}{4}(s(1-t)+\frac{1}{2}(t+1))})\quad & 
      \frac{3}{4}s+(1-s)\frac{1}{2} \leq& t \leq 1 }
  \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]